# Ubuntu Network Issues. How to add commands at startup?

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I don't know how but my MAC address on my network card lost its value so I had to put in a different one. I am new to Ubuntu and I don't know how to make these commands to load up when I boot up Ubuntu:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 hw eether [MACADDRESS]
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

Comment: How exactly did it loose it's value? If you want to set a cloned MAC address, you can use the network manager's settings to change the MAC address of a device.

Answer (score 1):

Don't configure network with low-level tools unless you know what you are doing. Use NetworkManager for MAC address setting instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your commands (as sudo) at the end of the file /etc/rc.local. There they will be executed at the very end of the boot process. Remember, the commands are also executed as root, not as your usual user.